# Weapons' upgrades unavailable in Metal Gear Rising

Tags: metal-gear-rising-revengeance

So, I've acidentally pressed *New Game*, which, unfortunately, erased all my previous purchases and status. I've already played through the game again on *Hard Mode* just to re-unlock my upgrades in the *Shop*. However, I've noticed that now I can only upgrade my weapons 1 time for each category. So, all my weapons have

> Attack = 1
>   Absorption = 1
>   Comsuption = 1

As opossed to previously

> Attack = 5 Absorption = 5 Comsuption = 5

**Question**: Are my weapons status really all 1 or are the powerful as  5 status (but without showing this explictly)?

Answer (score 1):

So, it seems that in order to fully unlock the upgrades it is necessary to play through the entirety of the storyline continuosly and getting all the **resistance+** as you progress.